# using ctrl-w gf open the filename under the cursor in newtab on the right side of the current tab in gvim?

Tags: vim, tabs, text-cursor

Is it possible to open the filename under the cursor using `ctrl-w` `gf` on the **right side** of the current tab in gvim ?

Currently when I opened the file its opening at the **very left side** of the gvim **window**, not even **immediate left** to the current tab.

Comment: try disabling all plugins and your own config, see if the problem still happen. Here I started a vim with all default config, the tab is created right after the current tab.

Comment: I tried the same by started the gvim by using "gvim -u NONE file_list" , but result was same. When I opened the files in the file list they files are opening in new tab on the very left side of the gvim window.

Comment: Opening the tab to the right is the default in Vim 7.4, tested using GVim
(without Cream) on Windows and compiled from source on Unix.

Comment: @ Anthony Geoghegan, unfortunately I am using Vim 7.0.237, so is there any option to do the same in this version... :-(